# object is not a function error

Tags: javascript

With following code:

```
var App = (function(param)
{
     return { foo : function() { alert(param); } }
})();

var d = App('test');
d.foo();
```

I get error message:

```
object is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is,

```
var App = (function(param){})();
```

This means that as soon as the statement is encountered, App is set to `{foo: function(){alert(param)}}`, but param is undefined

Try

```
var App = function(param)
{
 return { foo : function() { alert(param); } }
};

var d = App('test');
d.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the return value of an anonymous function to `App` and then trying to call `App` as if it were that function and not its return value.

This means that `App` is the object containing `foo`.

Either:

- Remove `()` from line 4
- Remove line 6 and place `'test'` between `(` and `)` on line 4 and replace `d` with `App` on the last line.